# how do I update a key field in a existing JSON string

Tags: java, json, updates

This code is used to get to a JSON string an change the asignee field to the user currently logged in.

This code does not work because the key `Full Name` is not updating to the parameter Asignee.  Can anybody tell me why its not working?

```
public void UpdateJsonAsign(String JSONstring, String Asignee){
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(JSONstring);
    obj.put("Full Name", Asignee);
}
```

Comment: Please provide the actual values of `JSONstring` and `Asignee` arguments. Also, why do you have all identifiers start from Capital letter? Please read about [java name conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Comment: json string ex: "Full Name":null

Comment: All I want to do is change the null within the JSON to an actual name.

Comment: If your `JSONstring` is literally `"\"Full Name\":null "` then it doesn't represent valid Json object, which should be enclosed in curly braces `{"Full Name":null }`.

Comment: That might be a dumb question but, how do you know it doesn't change the field? Do you use debugger? Print the JSON? Do you get an error? Could you post a bit more complete code sample because it's hard to tell what's wrong from your example.

Comment: The code has been Debugged the JSON within the URL does not change when I send a JSONstring and Asignee.

Comment: The extra code that I send to the method is:      parser.UpdateJsonAsign(TicketJSON, userattributes.getFullName());